# Boost's tokenizer different results under windows & linux

Tags: c++, linux, boost, tokenize, boost-tokenizer

I found some strange thing with boost::tokenizer.( boost version 1.53.0, 1.52.0 )

```
    tokenizer<escaped_list_separator<char> > tok(line);
    vec.assign( tok.begin(), tok.end() );
    ......
    double volume = lexical_cast<double>( vec[6] );
```

This code crashes under Linux( Ubuntu 12.04.2 and gcc version 4.6.3 )and works fine under Windows 7 ( VS 2010 Express ).
The string( 'line' variable ) which I want to prepare is :

```
    2012-12-03,09:30:00.000,35.3,35.5,35.26,35.47,26963
```

Under linux:

```
     vec[6] is '26963\r'
```

and lexical_cast is crashed.

Under Windows:

```
     vec[6] is '26963'
```

works fine.

Is this correct behavoir?

Comment: Has line come from a file? How do you read it?

Comment: The problem is with your input, not Boost. Windows treats `\r\n` as newline, but for Linux, it's just `\n`. Your file probably has Windows encoding which confuses your Linux program.

Comment: Thank's, you are absolutely right. Thank you very match again.